# Unity, Coordinates of the button

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, coordinates

How to get the bottom left and top right corner of a button in screen coordinates if the button is on an Overlay Canvas? It should depend on screen.width and screen.height.

Comment: To the phantom close voter, refrain from flagging this Unity question as _"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetWorldCorners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html), when the canvas is an overlay canvas, the world positions are equal to screen positions.

```
var corners = new Vector3[4];
GetComponent<RectTransform>().GetWorldCorners(corners);

// corners[0]:  bottom-left
// corners[2]:  top-right
```

If your canvas is an screen camera canvas, you need to convert them with camera's `WorldToScreenPoint` method.